How would I simulate an Intransitive zIndex in React Native? (A > B > C > A)
I am trying to create this effect, which can be found in the Spotify UI:

It seems that there are the following components:

A parent <View> (black)

The child <View> (pink)

The <Text> inside the child

The <Image>, which is a square shape, part of which is visible (on the pink background) and part of which is obscured (behind the black)


The problem is, how do they make this work zIndex-wise?

The parent <View> appears above the <Image> - "P > I"

The <Image> appears above the child <View> - "I > C"

The child <View> appears above the parent <View> - "C > P"


This leaves us with P > I > C > P, so P > P which isn't possible with normal numbers, like those that zIndex is set to. This kind of property is called intransitivity and appears in situations like the game Rock Paper Scissors, where R > S > P > R.
Nevertheless, Spotify somehow managed to pull this off. Does anybody have any idea as to how this might be achieved?
Maybe the fact that React Native uses hierarchy-specific zIndexes rather than global ones could somehow help?

It just looks like the image is clipped by the pink view's bounds..?

@AKX Exactly. How do you achieve that?

@AKX your comment stimulated me to find the answer. Thank you! I posted it below.

I found the solution - don't use zIndex. It's simply overflow: "hidden".
<View style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}> {/* pink box */}
  {/* all content inside here will be clipped by the boundary of this view */}
</View>


To achieve this design in React Native, where the z-index relationship doesn’t seem to match (P > I > C > P), you can use a combination of absolute positioning and layer specific methods One way a you can use it to achieve the desired effect:

Parent <View> (black background) .
Child <View> (pink background) .
Type <View> in the child
Partially visible image (half on pink background and half on black parent background).

Let’s break down the usage:
The parent concept will act as a black background.
The image becomes quite stable. This makes it partly visible in the child’s mind and partly obscured outside the parent’s mind.
The child view will be placed above the parent view and text will be added.
Here is a code sample in React Native to illustrate this.
const SpotifyLayout = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.parent}>
      <Image source={{ uri: 'your-image-url' }} style={styles.image} />
      <View style={styles.child}>
        <Text style={styles.text}> ... </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  parent: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  image: {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    top: 50,
    left: 50,
    zIndex: 1,
  },
  child: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    backgroundColor: 'pink',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    zIndex: 2,
  },
  text: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 18,
  },
});

Parent Style (styles.parent): This is a black background view.
Image (styles.image): Absolutely in the parent view. The zIndex is set to 1 to place it above the parent view but below the child view.
Child view (styles.child): Located in the parent view with a pink background. The zIndex is set to 2 to place it above the parent view and image.
Text ( styles . text ): Located in the child view .

Perhaps you shouldn't use z-index. I think using backgrounds will be sufficient.
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const MusicCard = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Muzyka</Text>
      <Image
        source={{ uri: 'https://path-to-your-image.png' }} // replace with your image path
        style={styles.image}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#d21b78', // pink background color
    padding: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    margin: 20,
    height: 200,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    position: 'relative',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#fff',
  },
  image: {
    width: 100,
    height: 150,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 10,
    right: 10,
    transform: [{ rotate: '-10deg' }],
  },
});

export default MusicCard;

